# Best way to implement a graph in C++?

Tags: c++, graph, adjacency-list

I'm looking to implement a constant, unordered, unweighted, sparse graph (ie. edges do not move). However, I will be doing lots of vertex swap operations, whereby the ordering of the vertices change.

Eg, one way is to use a vector of unordered_sets + the adjacency list structure:

```
0: 1 2 3
1: 0 2
2: 0 1
3: 0
```

swap 0 and 3:

```
0: 3
1: 3 2
2: 3 1
3: 1 2 0
```

What is the best implementation in C++?

Comment: Another factor will be how sparse the graph is expected to be.

Comment: Please start by learning a bit on programmatic representations of graphs then Google up how to do it in C++.  Your question is specific enough to qualify as a good question IMO however this information is not at all obscure to learn on your own.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the graph is sparse.

Answer (score 3):

Look into [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html).  It will probably work for your needs, but if it doesn't, it's documentation may be a good starting point to learn about the subject, before you start trying to roll your own.

Edit: If you're expecting to work with sparse graphs, the [adjacency list](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html) version is probably the implementation you want to look into first.  Note that you can tweak the performance characteristics of a boost adjacency_list graph by changing the underlying data structures used to implement it (via template argument).

Edit: In regards to the vertex swapping you're describing, probably the easiest way to do this is to set up a vertex type where the vertex can remain in place, but its properties can easily be swapped with another.  The [Bundled Properties](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html) mechanism is one way to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

[boost::graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) perhaps.

It has several implementations, and you can specify multiple parameters per vertex. Further investigation is left as an exercise for the student.

Comment: I think using boost may perhaps be overkill, and AFAIK it doesn't (easily) support a swap pattern

Comment: not at all, boos::graph is an excellent solution, there is a lot of vertex manipulation available in the library, so i think you'll be surprised once you get up to speed with it.